# C# / VB.Net issue: VB.Net fills string array but C# doesn't

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6

I'm working with referenced VB6 DLL's. The problem is that the results of a method/function call are not the same. Below the code examples:

First VB.Net

```
Dim Validations() As String
myErr = myEntry.ValidateLine(Validations)
```

When validation fails, the string array Validations is filled with the error description string. I've tried to accomplish the same in C#:

```
private string[] valArray = null;
sdkError = sdkEntry.ValidateLine(valArray);
```

Does anyone have an idea why I can't get C# to fill the string array?

Additionally, the function in VB is called with ref to a System.Array ...

ValidateLine(ref System.Array ValErrors), perhaps it has something to do with this?

Comment: Have you tried with ArrayList ?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that VB is implicitly passing your variable by reference. You could try doing the same thing in C#:

```
sdkError = sdkEntry.ValidateLine(ref valArray);
```

(It's not immediately clear how you're invoking the VB DLL, mind you.)

Answer (score 0):

Your VB creates and empty array, your C# creates a null array. I'm guessing the VB dll needs a non null value.

Try swapping your C# to this:

```
private string[] valArray = new string[]{};
```

Comment: The DLL still isn't going to be able to populate that array. (Also, `= new string[0]` would be simpler, or just `= {};`.)

Comment: The VB is also creating a null array reference, identical to the C#